# How to configure NFSv4 only server in CentOS 6.10

Tags: linux, nfs, centos-6

I am trying to configure NFSv4 only server in CentOS 6.10

I've disabled NFS v2 and v3 using this conf file `/etc/sysconfig/nfs`

```
MOUNTD_NFS_V2="no"
MOUNTD_NFS_V3="no"
RPCNFSDARGS="-N 2 -N 3"
```

I followed this [link](https://serverfault.com/q/530908/128874) for reference.

As per [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/902013) document NFSv4 doesn't need rpcbind anymore.

But if I start nfs service without starting rpcbind service I am getting below error. NFS service is not starting.

```
[root@server ~]# service rpcbind status
rpcbind is stopped
[root@server ~]# service nfs restart
Shutting down NFS daemon:                                  [FAILED]
Shutting down NFS mountd:                                  [  OK  ]
Shutting down NFS quotas:                                  [FAILED]
Shutting down NFS services:                                [  OK  ]
Starting NFS services:                                     [  OK  ]
Starting NFS quotas: Cannot register service: RPC: Unable to receive; errno = Connection refused
rpc.rquotad: unable to register (RQUOTAPROG, RQUOTAVERS, udp).
                                                           [FAILED]
Starting NFS mountd:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting NFS daemon: rpc.nfsd: writing fd to kernel failed: errno 111 (Connection refused)
rpc.nfsd: unable to set any sockets for nfsd
                                                           [FAILED]
[root@server ~]#
```

If I start rpcbind then nfs service is starting properly.

```
[root@server ~]# service rpcbind restart
Stopping rpcbind:                                          [  OK  ]
Starting rpcbind:                                          [  OK  ]
[root@server ~]# service nfs restart
Shutting down NFS daemon:                                  [  OK  ]
Shutting down NFS mountd:                                  [  OK  ]
Shutting down NFS quotas:                                  [  OK  ]
Shutting down NFS services:                                [  OK  ]
Shutting down RPC idmapd:                                  [  OK  ]
Starting NFS services:                                     [  OK  ]
Starting NFS quotas:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting NFS mountd:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting NFS daemon:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting RPC idmapd:                                       [  OK  ]
[root@server ~]#
```

How to start nfsv4 without rpcbind ? Is it possible ?

NFSv4 still need rpcbind ?

My kernel version is `2.6.32-754.6.3.el6.x86_64`